# Guardar en una colección de mongodb, el resultado de una función en javascript con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo la siguiente duda: **de que manera puedo guardar el resultado de una función en una colección de MongoDB.**
prácticamente lo que quiero hacer es al enviar el formulario se guarde todos los inputs y el resultado de una función aritmética que se ejecuta en una función. he estado buscando la manera de poder hacerlo pero aún no encuentro nada útil les agradecería una ayuda con eso o algún link donde se hable del tema.

función que se ejecuta en el submit del botón:

```
function Aplicar() {

  $("#form_approve")[0].reportValidity();

  var resultado = 0; var ingresos = 0;
  var cualitativa = 0; var prestamo = 0;
  var p_ingresos = 0;
  var p_cualitativa = 0; var p_prestamo = 0;

  ingresos = parseInt(document.getElementById("tran_loan").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("tran_payment").value);

  prestamo = parseInt(document.getElementById("tran_fortnight").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("tran_cony_fornight").value);

  var iSum = 0;
  $('#form_approve select').each(function () {
    iSum = iSum + parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  cualitativa = iSum - ingresos - prestamo;

  //peso en %
  p_cualitativa = ((cualitativa / 150) * 100);
  p_ingresos = ((ingresos / 20) * 100);
  p_prestamo = ((prestamo / 20) * 100);

  resultado = Math.round((p_cualitativa * 20/100) + (p_ingresos * 30/100) + (p_prestamo * 50/100));

  //console.log((p_cualitativa * 0.2),(p_ingresos * 0.3) , (p_prestamo * 0.5), resultado);

  return resultado;
}
```

controller

```
const TransacCtrl = {};

// Models
const Transac = require("../models/trans");


//se muestra el formulario
TransacCtrl.renderapproveForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('form_approve');
};

TransacCtrl.createNewtrans = async (req, res) => {
    const { tran_age, tran_stat, tran_sons, tran_house, tran_house_time, tran_job_time, tran_account, tran_bike, tran_apps, tran_css,
        tran_insurance, tran_att, tran_talk, tran_pan_time, tran_legal, tran_loan, tran_payment, tran_fortnight, tran_cony_fornight, tran_date,
        tran_result } = req.body;


    const errors = [];
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render("form_approve", {
            errors
        });
    } else {
        const newTransac = new Transac({
            tran_age, tran_stat, tran_sons, tran_house, tran_house_time, tran_job_time, tran_account, tran_bike, tran_apps, tran_css,
            tran_insurance, tran_att, tran_talk, tran_pan_time, tran_legal, tran_loan, tran_payment, tran_fortnight, tran_cony_fornight, tran_date,
            tran_result/*este campo debería ir el resultado de la función*/
        });
        /* newNote.user = req.user.id;*/
        await newTransac.save();
        req.flash("success_msg", "Datos de formulario guardados");
        res.redirect("profile");
    }
};


module.exports = TransacCtrl;
```

muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como envías la información al controlador? 
Podrías añadir el schema de la coleccion `Transac`?

Comment: @planta4 lo solucioné agregando los cálculos de la función en el controlador

Comment: gracias por responde @nikos. Si puedes añade la solucion realizada y validada, asi no se queda pendiente de responder esta pregunta, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Así quedó todo lo que necesitaba.

Modelo

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");


const TransacSchema = new Schema(
    {
        cli_ced: {
            type: String   
        },
        tran_age: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_stat: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_sons: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_house: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_house_time: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_job_time: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_account: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_bike: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_apps: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_css: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_insurance: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_att: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_talk: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_pan_time: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_legal: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_loan: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_payment: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_fortnight: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_cony_fornight: {
            type: Number
        },
        tran_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date()
        },
        tran_result: {
            type: Number
        },
        cli_id : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' }]

    });


module.exports = model("Tran", TransacSchema);
```

Controlador:

```
TransacCtrl.createNewtrans = async (req, res) => {
        
    try {        
    
    var id = req.query.id;
        
            //let apprform = await Tran.find({ cli_ced: id /*req.session.cli_id*/ });
            Tran.findOne({ cli_id: id }, async (err, apprform) => {
        
                const { tran_age, tran_stat, tran_sons, tran_house, tran_house_time, tran_job_time, tran_account, tran_bike, tran_apps, tran_css,
                    tran_insurance, tran_att, tran_talk, tran_pan_time, tran_legal, tran_loan, tran_payment, tran_fortnight, tran_cony_fornight
                } = req.body;
        
                var xsum = 0;
                var resultado = 0; var ingresos = 0;
                var cualitativa = 0; var prestamo = 0;
                var p_ingresos = 0;
                var p_cualitativa = 0; var p_prestamo = 0;
        
                for (var key in req.body) {
                    let value = req.body[key];
                    xsum = xsum + parseInt(value);
                }
        
                prestamo = parseInt(req.body.tran_loan) + parseInt(tran_payment);
                ingresos = parseInt(req.body.tran_fortnight) + parseInt(tran_cony_fornight);
                cualitativa = xsum - prestamo - ingresos;
        
                p_cualitativa = ((cualitativa / 150) * 100);
                p_ingresos = ((ingresos / 20) * 100);
                p_prestamo = ((prestamo / 20) * 100);
        
                resultado = Math.round((p_cualitativa * 20 / 100) + (p_ingresos * 30 / 100) + (p_prestamo * 50 / 100));
        
                const newTransac = new Tran({
                    tran_age, tran_stat, tran_sons, tran_house, tran_house_time, tran_job_time, tran_account, tran_bike, tran_apps, tran_css,
                    tran_insurance, tran_att, tran_talk, tran_pan_time, tran_legal, tran_loan, tran_payment, tran_fortnight, tran_cony_fornight,
                    tran_result: resultado
                });
                newTransac.cli_ced = id;
        
                if (!apprform) {
                    console.log(apprform);
                    await newTransac.save();
                    res.redirect('resultf');
                }
                else {
                    console.log(apprform);
                    req.flash('appr1msg', 'No se puede volver a crear un formulario, presione el botón editar.');
                    return res.redirect('/clients');
                }
        
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            });
        };
```